# How to parse json using json4s so that let primitive values become custom case class?

Tags: scala, json4s

I want to use case class to replace primitive type in json4s, since I want to put business method in these case class.

for example:

```
import org.json4s.{CustomSerializer, DefaultFormats, NoTypeHints}
import org.json4s.JsonAST.{JField, JInt, JObject}
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.read

object Json4sExercise {

  trait ObjectHolder[T] {
  }

  case class IntValue(v: Int) extends ObjectHolder[Int]

  case class StringValue(v: String) extends ObjectHolder[String]

  class IntSerializer extends CustomSerializer[IntValue](format => ( {
    case JInt(x) => IntValue(x.toInt)
  }, {
    case IntValue(x) => JInt(BigInt(x))
  }
  ))

  implicit val formats =  Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new IntSerializer

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(read[Map[String, _]](""" {"price":350} """))
  }

}
```

But instead of what I wanted: Map(price -> IntValue(x:350)), it printed Map(price -> 350)

Comment: BEWARE: [Json4s has not fixed security vulnerabilities](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial) that allows DoS/DoW attacks for systems that accepts untrusted input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific with the type you want to read

```
println(read[Map[String, IntValue]](""" {"price":350} """))
Map(price -> IntValue(350))
```